# How to use a computed column in an if/else

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, triggers, sql-server-2012, calculated-columns

I got a problem with my trigger: It wont recognize my table that stores the computed column that I need the data from.

My table looks like this and consists of multiple computed columns:
[image: my table]

My problem is with the In_Months column, part of my trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Balance_monthly]
ON [dbo].[Balance]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @test int;
    DECLARE @amount int;
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF Balance.In_Months % 12 = 0
        SET @amount = 3;
```

It doesn't allow me to Update my trigger because it can't find my table.

Comment: SQL Server triggers fire once per statement, so you need to reference the `inserted` and/or `deleted` tables to access the changed data, and you need to realise that those tables can contain *multiple* rows.

Comment: Generally, you write one or more set-based queries that achieve the goals of your trigger, coping with e.g. `inserted` might contain 4 rows, 2 of which have `Balance.In_Months % 12 = 0` and 2 of which do not. However, you've not told us what the overall goal of this trigger is, so I can't suggest any specific code at the moment.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? Is there an amount column that should be set to 3 when In_Month is 12,24,36 ?

Comment: I think you guys understand my If sentence but since it doesn't recognize my table it wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to point you in the right direction. It doesn't give a useful answer, just a valid answer. It just demonstrates how triggers work.

Seems you want to estimate some data being inserted. However more than 1 row can be inserted or updated.

Creation of a test table:

```
CREATE table balance(in_months int)
```

Creation of trigger. I am selecting the 3 for each row where In_Months can be divided by 12

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Balance_monthly]
ON [dbo].[Balance]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @amount int;
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT @amount= sum(case when INSERTED.In_Months % 12 = 0 then 3 else 0 end)
    FROM INSERTED
    SELECT @amount
END
```

Inserting into table to active the trigger:

```
INSERT balance(In_Months) values(12),(13),(24)
```

Result is 6(3*2) because 2 of the inserted values(12 and 24) can be divided by 12

Comment: The     SELECT @amount= sum(case when INSERTED.In_Months % 12 =     0 then 3 else 0 end)
    FROM INSERTED was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I'll fix that, anyway thanks for solving my problem.

Answer (score -1):

use alter

```
ALTER TRIGGER [Balance_monthly] ON [dbo].[Balance]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @test int;
DECLARE @amount int;
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF In_Months % 12 = 0
    SET @amount = 3;
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this statement is not recognized in this context.

Comment: Yes I do, but it wont allow me to update because it can't find my table